# How to get gcc to generate decent code that checks if a buffer is full of NUL bytes?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, micro-optimization

I'm implementing a program that parses tape archives. Part of the parser logic is checking for an end-of-archive marker which is a 512-byte block full of NUL bytes. I wrote the following code for this purpose, expecting gcc to optimize this well:

```
int is_eof_block(const char usth[static 512])
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        if (usth[i] != '\0')
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

But to my surprise, gcc still generates terrible code for that, even though I explicitly allow it to access the whole 512 bytes in the buffer:

```
is_eof_block:
    leaq    512(%rdi), %rax
    jmp .L239
    .p2align 4,,10
.L243:
    addq    $1, %rdi
    cmpq    %rax, %rdi
    je  .L242
.L239:
    cmpb    $0, (%rdi)
    je  .L243
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
.L242:
    movl    $1, %eax
    ret
```

I expected gcc to generate something like this or even SIMD code:

```
is_eof_block:
    mov $64,%ecx
    xor %eax,%eax
    repz scasq
    setz %al
    ret
```

How can I rewrite the code such that it is still portable (as in: does not use non-C99 language extensions and works on architectures that do not support misaligned memory access) but compiles to better machine code on common architectures such as amd64 and AArch32?

### Benchmark

I wrote the following microbenchmark to demonstrate the time difference. You can define `MISALIGNED` to a positive integer to test with misaligned buffers.

#### benchmark.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TESTS 10000000
#ifndef MISALIGNED
# define MISALIGNED 0
#endif

char testarray[512 + MISALIGNED];

extern int is_eof_block(const char[static 512]);

int main()
{
    size_t i, j;
    clock_t begin, end;

    fprintf(stderr, "testing %d times\n", TESTS);
    fprintf(stderr, "no byte set to 1... ");
    begin = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < TESTS; i++)
        if (!is_eof_block(testarray + MISALIGNED)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nWrong test result in iteration %zu!\n", i);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    end = clock();
    fprintf(stderr, "%fs\n", (end - begin) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    fprintf(stderr, "with non-null byte... ");
    begin = clock();

    for (i = j = 0; i < TESTS; i++) {
        testarray[MISALIGNED + j] = '\0';
        j = (j + 47) & 511;
        testarray[MISALIGNED + j] = '1';

        if (is_eof_block(testarray + MISALIGNED)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nWrong test result in iteration %zu!\n", i);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }       
    }

    end = clock();
    fprintf(stderr, "%fs\n", (end - begin) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### is_eof_block_c.c

```
#include <stddef.h>

int is_eof_block(const char test[static 512])
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
        if (test[i] != '\0')
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

#### is_eof_block_asm.s

```
    .text
    .globl is_eof_block
    .type is_eof_block,@function

    .align 16
is_eof_block:
    mov $64,%ecx
    xor %eax,%eax
    repz scasq
    setz %al
    ret
    .size is_eof_block,.-is_eof_block
```

Here is the output with the C implementation of `is_eof_block` linked in:

```
testing 10000000 times
no byte set to 1... 2.281250s
with non-null byte... 1.195312s
```

and here is the assembly version:

```
testing 10000000 times
no byte set to 1... 0.476562s
with non-null byte... 0.320312s
```

Both have been compiled with a gcc 5 with the sole optimization option being `-O3`. Passing various `-march=...` flags didn't change the code. The difference is about a factor of four. With a misaligned buffer, the assembly implementation is roughly 3% slower whereas there is no difference with the C implementation.

Comment: If you want specific assembly to be generated, why don't you simply inline it?  The optimizer is only so smart.  It doesn't know what you *mean*, only what you *say*. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Because that would be unportable. The goal is not to generate specific assembly, the goal is to give the compiler enough information to generate proper code. Inline assembly for every architecture is also tedious to maintain.

Comment: Why should it access every byte in the buffer? It's more efficient to abort early and not touch every byte. If the first byte is not 0, then the whole loop can break before pulling in the whole buffer into the cache.

Comment: @Art It doesn't need to, but the `static` allows the compiler to generate code that touches more bytes that I do in the code. This might allow the compiler to e.g. test a double word at once instead of testing every byte.

Comment: Is that code really slower? Did you benchmark against your assembler code?

Comment: @Olaf No, as a matter of fact I didn't. Let me draft up a quick benchmark.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations ?

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that gcc doesn't use the bigger than byte instructions here because you give it no indication that the block is correctly aligned.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes. I compiled with `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native`.

Comment: Not sure, but doesn*t `static` just guarantee the array really has that many entries as given by the index? (something normal for other languages) It does not guarantee a specific alignment. Also more complex instructions are executed by the CPU in microcode and have to be broken down into more internal RISC-OPs on x86. Even on good old Z80 such instructions sometimes were significantly slower than simple operations (which is the reason RISC was invented).

Comment: @Olaf Alignment doesn't matter on x86. With Core 2 and newer, misaligned access has no penalty except if it goes over a cache line boundary. But even then, gcc usually generates extra code to deal with the misalignment.

Comment: It still might add penalties in the RISC-core. But even if not, the bus-interface might add overhead anyway, or - more likely - generate much the same RISC code for both versions. x86 is quite a beast when it comes to code execution.

Comment: @Olaf Added a benchmark to prove my suspicions. Note that the array is in the L1 cache in this benchmark, which reflects the usage scenario.

Comment: @Olaf Again: Beginning with the Core 2 microarchitecure, misaligned access has no penalty except if it goes over a cache line boundary. You can find this information in the Intel manuals.

Comment: I did not write about missaligned data-accesses, but RISC instructions. Did you try `alignas ...` (what would be the problem with C11? And  did you optimise for core 2+? Provide the compiler options.

Comment: @Olaf In this case, I don't understand your question. I already wrote further above that gcc is perfectly capable of generating code that deals with misaligned data and usually generates fast code even for such cases.

Comment: @Vorsprung I outlined my reasons in other comments (portability has priority, so no inline assembly but I'd still like to get fast code). The tar example is only a use case of such code, I'm interested in this topic in general.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I talked about the internal RISC code. x86 does not execute x86 instructions natively since - IIRC PPro or even P1.

Comment: @Olaf Yes. I know that. But then I don't understand your problem. Again: The Intel manuals specify that there is no penalty with misaligned memory access, unless the access goes over a cache line boundary. Why do you keep claiming that there is a penalty where the manual clearly states that there is none? And `alignas` cannot be applies to arguments in a meaningful way.

Comment: You are on the wrong track. I talked about instructions, you about data. Anyway, to get back to the subject: how about a union of two arrays: `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` (for x64 `uint64_t`)?

Comment: @Olaf That either breaks the interface or doesn't work on machines that don't support misaligned access depending on how you do it. And again: I don't understand about what overhead you are talking. the benchmark clearly shows how terrible the naïve C implementation is and I still don't understand what “might add penalties to the RISC code” is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Olaf More tests show that the assembly implementation is 3% slower on misaligned data, which is consistent with what the Intel manuals say (due to the eight cache-line crossing memory accesses).

Comment: Complex instructions like the looping ones are emulated in microcode and with multiple RISC instructions, while simple instructions don't use microcode, but execute directly. That might make a set of simple x86 instructions execute faster than the (as x86) more compact complex instructions. Additionally, if they need more RISC instructions, they eat up the internal RISC-instruction cache (which is not the L1 x86 instruction cache!). Even if a synthetic benchmark is faster, it might be slower in productive code. x86 is the far by most complex architecture.

Comment: @Olaf That's true. But do you doubt that I could get the compiler to generate better code for a function that does the same thing as this function using only portable means (which is the original question)?

Comment: Disclaimer: this does not mean it _will_, but just might explain why gcc does not behqave as expected. Another explanation is: an automated tool cannot optimise all possible code optimal. You should be happy, so there still is work for us humans left.

Comment: You might not be able to parametrise the compiler (at least) in a portable way, yes. There still is reason you have to write assembler code for for optimum speed. Question is if it is really worth the effort here. How fast can you read from the medium? And how much overhead does the check add to the rest?

Comment: @Olaf The question is not to generate the fastest possible code on one platform with a specific set of compiler options. The question is to rewrite this function so it yields better assembly code in general on a broad range of optimizing compilers. The tar program is only a motivation for the problem (and reading compressed tar archives can be fast), functions like this occur often and since the libc doesn't provide this, a portable implementation is needed.

Comment: This incredibly dirty/hacky/UB version seems to be pretty fast, even though it is a major violation against multiple rules: `typedef uint_fast16_t fast_t;

int is_eof_block(const char usth[static 512])
{
  for (const fast_t* i = (const fast_t*)usth; i < (const fast_t*)(usth+512); i++)
      if (*i != 0)
          return 0;

  return 1;
}`  Maybe something along those lines but without the dirty hacks? (Violates pointer conversion rules, strict aliasing etc etc)

Comment: @Lundin Possibly. That lies outside of the realm of ISO 9899 though. Hm...

Comment: `repz scas` is unfortunately *not* highly optimized in microcode the way `rep movs` and `rep stos` are on Intel CPUs.  A normal loop is usually at least as good.  Check [Agner Fog's insn tables and optimization guide](http://agner.org/optimize/).  `rep* scas` takes >= 2*count cycles, but a normal loop with integer code can sustain at least one 8B load per cycle.  With SSE2 you can do much better than that (and hopefully compilers will at some point be smart and optimize your code).  `OR`ing together a couple chunks for every test is not a bad idea.  Maybe ORing bytes can get it to do 8B checks

Comment: @PeterCordes The `repz scasq` code was just an example for how shitty the code gcc generates is. I agree that a better implementation must be possible.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think it's a combination of gcc not being good at merging narrow accesses into one wide access, and the default being not to unroll loops.  Did you have a look at what clang does?  Hmm, clang's not better.  Maybe because the C source won't access memory beyond a non-zero byte, so the asm won't either?

Comment: gcc has a bugzilla, feel free to report possible enhancements there. Generally, vectorizers are unhappy when there is control flow in the loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes clang doesn't do any better.

Comment: @Olaf An [AVX implemention](https://gist.github.com/fuzxxl/a5e14dffa2c5af8942c6) yields a 15-fold speedup over the `rep scasq` version (63 fold speedup over the C code), showing again how terrible the original C code compiles. Now I'm hoping that the AVX code is not plain wrong.

Comment: It looks unrolled more than needed, and doesn't fold memory operands at all.  You only need two vector accumulators to max out two loads per clock.  Also, you might want to consider an early-out to save main-memory bandwidth in the case where the first cache-line of a block is non-zero.  Testing just the first 8B is going to catch most cases.  `cmpq $0, %(rdi)`, then AVX OR everything together.  You could use AVX `vorps` instead of AVX2 `vpor`, but on Haswell & Broadwell that would cost you a factor of 2 in throughput in the (rare?) hot-in-L1 case.  Skylake runs `vorps` on any port.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah sorry, I'm not very familiar with vectorization. I fiddled around with this an two hours ago already an improved it to [this](https://gist.github.com/fuzxxl/908138fb07f0b93733db). I didn't even knew that you could have memory operands in AVX.

Comment: @FUZxxl: why not just use intrinsics?  That will let the compiler be smart about inlining it, and not needing `VZEROUPPER` for every 512B.  Also it can directly test the flags set by `PTEST`, instead of requiring it to use `setcc` to make a return value, then probably the caller has to `test %eax, %eax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I made the AVX implementation just to find out how fast it can possibly get. For this problem, I want a portable solution because the code is going to be used in a portably project. It doesn't have to be the fastest code possible, but something that is not 70 times slower than an implementation in assembly would be great.

Comment: @FUZxxl: you should easily be able to saturate memory bandwidth with SSE2.  It's baseline for 64bit.  `por` (`_mm_or_si128`) some vectors together, `pcmpeqd` against a vector of all-zeros, then `movmskps` to get a scalar integer variable.  In C, make sure it's `0xf` (all four bits == 1 means all four vector elements == 0).

Comment: @PeterCordes But that's not a portable solution. Portability is more important than speed here, an unportable solution is not acceptable.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I'm talking about doing that in an `#ifdef __SSE2__` or something.  As a fallback, do the same thing but with `unsigned long` variables or something.  Is there any way you can guarantee the alignment of your 512B buffer?  If not, then you might need to detect / decide if unaligned accesses are allowed on the target architecture.  (Be careful with detection based on the host in the non-cross-compile case, though.  Possibly some implementations of an ISA might allow unaligned accesses while other implementations don't.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Honestly, I expected my code to have some trivial mistake. I expect that there is a simple way in which I can nudge gcc to generate better code if possible. But this seems to be not the case... Maybe the optimization is not worth the effort after all. I could ensure alignment of the buffer (with the method Lundin laid out in his answer) but then the code would be much more difficult to understand and to maintain. I could also use conditional compilation but this impedes maintenance and testability as I cannot test all code path on each architecture.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think you can save a lot of CPU time, and make your code more hypertheading-friendly by at least having it loop in at least 4 or 8B chunks (`long`).  Lundin's method looks fine, but could be simplified.  Use `aligned_alloc` or `posix_memalign` for your i/o buffers if you dynamically allocate.   Or maybe test for the buffer being aligned and use a fallback if it's not?  But that sucks compared to aligning i/o buffers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Tricky... right now my buffers are automatic variables. I can trivially align them with `alignas`. Maybe I should leave it at that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @FUZxxl: You should probably make `read` system calls with a buffer size of ~half L1 cache since you're planning to scan it.  So 16kiB is a good choice to balance syscall overhead with having data still cached from the memcpy from the pagecache that happens inside the kernel's `read(2)`.  Or maybe larger, like 64k to 128k. 16k is prob. fine on the stack, but if this is a stand-alone program, a static buffer is a good choice.  (In a lib, you don't want to leave 16k of dirty memory around when it's not useful.)  BTW, what does `arr[static 512]` mean in C?  C++ doesn't allow `static` there.

Comment: @PeterCordes The `static` is a guarantee that up to 512 bytes of memory are accessible. It's a hint to the compiler that it may read more memory than you explicitly do. In my concrete example (tar files) there is one 512 byte header and then file contents (which I skip). But I keep your advice in mind for other use cases. Thank you for helping me so much.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I thought `const char usth[512]` already meant that it was known to be a 512B object.  I mean, you can do a `sizeof` even without `static`.  I thought you were scanning file contents when creating tar archives to opportunistically detect zero chunks that the tar format can represent much more compactly.  Like GNU `tar --sparse`.  Or when going from one tar to another.  (There are already tools and libraries that do that, BTW.  Do you need to write your own?)

Comment: @PeterCordes When declaring a function parameter, any attempts to declare arrays actually declare pointers, `type[512]` is equal to `type*` and the length information is ignored. Thus the `static` syntax was invented. I'm using this function to detect the *end-of-archive* marker which is two 512 byte blocks of zero bytes. I recognize this is overkill as the marker occurs only once in every archive but I'm interested in the problem in general (for portable projects) as this kind of problem pops up every once in a while.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ok, I see.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array explains the same thing you just did, that I was wrong and `char arr[512]` doesn't let the compiler read parts of the array that the function wouldn't normally.  I was making an incorrect assumption based on how multidimensional array function args work: `int foo(int arr[][10][20]);`.  Anyway, this efficient-code-for-detecting-all-zero-buffers is something I've looked at before.  pre-allocation (`fallocate`) results in files that are all-zero, but don't technically have holes.  `fallocate(1)` has a `-d` option to dig holes.

Comment: @PeterCordes Note that a series of 1024 NUL bytes is not large enough to become a hole in most file systems as many of them use a block size of 4096 bytes.

Comment: @FUZxxl: yep, FS block size = memory page size = 4k for almost everything on Linux.  The algorithm for checking a buffer for all-zero is the same!  You can fully-unroll with AVX for buffers as small as 512, but other than that there's no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the genuinely helpful comments to the question, I have decided to go with the original C code. Thanks all of you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version that touches every byte and seems to be 2-3x faster than the original function *in your test harness* (I'm not convinced it reflects reality accurately):

```
int
is_eof_block1(const char usth[static 512])
{
        unsigned int i;
        int res = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
                res |= usth[i];
        return res == 0;
}
```

Here's a version that optimizes for readability and not wasting peoples time and trying to outclever the people who wrote your compiler/libc (it's much faster than your assembler, at least on my machine):

```
int
is_eof_block2(const char usth[static 512])
{
        const static char foo[512];
        return !memcmp(usth, foo, sizeof(foo));
}
```

Comment: The first version is just as fast as my handwritten assembly for the all-zero case with gcc and faster than my handwritten assembly with clang. Both are a little bit slower for the not-all-zero case though. The second version is about 50% slower than the handwritten assembly, although it's nicely succinct.

Comment: I tried to do something similar to the 2nd version but to call memcmp repeatedly in a loop with the size of the preferred aligned type. GCC doesn't seem very keen to inline memcmp for me though, so it turned out horrible inefficient even with -O3.

Comment: Oh. I see. the `memcmp` version is only faster for me when the function is in the same compilation unit as the test harness because gcc inlines everything and knows that  `memcmp` is a pure function and removes the useless looping around it. Heh.

Comment: @Art Which is why I made sure to have the benchmarked functions in a different translation unit and turned off LTO.

Comment: Replace `for (i = 0; i < 512; i++)
                res |= usth[i];` by `for (i = 0; i < 512/8; i+=8)
                res |= *(uint64_t*)&usth[i];` and declare `res` as `uint64_t`. Cuts by 8 the number of loops.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter That's not portable. It doesn't work on platforms that disallow misaligned memory access.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one version which (naively) believes that the compiler will do the best possible job if you give it one of the stdint.h `_fast` types:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint_fast16_t fast_t; // 16 since 512 can't fit in 8 bits

#define FAST_SIZE (512/sizeof(fast_t))

typedef union  // union to guarantee there's no aliasing mishaps
{
  char   usth [512];
  fast_t fast [FAST_SIZE];

} block_t;


// misc sanity checks:
_Static_assert(512%sizeof(fast_t) == 0, "This should never happen");
_Static_assert(sizeof(block_t) == 512,  "Padding gone crazy");


int is_eof_block(const block_t* block)
{
  for(const fast_t* i=&block->fast[0]; i<block->fast+FAST_SIZE; i++)
  {
    if(*i != 0)
      return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}


int main (void)
{
  block_t block = {0};

  printf("%d", is_eof_block(&block));
}
```

The loop can be replaced with array + iterator instead of pointer arithmetic. Might be faster or slower, I haven't benchmarked it.

EDIT:

Array + iterator version. Which is why I used `uint_fast16_t` - I was hoping that "`fast_t`" would do a better job than `size_t` and then it has to be at least large enough to contain the value 512.

```
int is_eof_block(const block_t* block)
{
  for(fast_t i=0; i<FAST_SIZE; i++)
  {
    if(block->fast[i] != 0)
      return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for choosing `uint_fast16_t` as opposed to `uint_fast8_t` or `uint_fast32_t`?

Comment: @FUZxxl I fiddled around with the array + iterator version similar to what you have in the OP, and then I declared the iterator as `fast_t i` rather than `size_t`. So it had to be 16 bits to fit the value 512. Hang on, I'll post both versions.

Comment: But you never store an index into the array in a `fast_t`. I'm not sure why it needs to be this way.

Comment: @FUZxxl It was a remain from earlier code, check the version I just posted in an edit and you'll see why. I can't guarantee that `FAST_SIZE` will be a value less than 256.

Answer (score 1):

Since the block is known to be 512 bytes fetch each 16 byte group into an UInt64, then test against zero.   That should cut down on the loop overhead.

A possible workaround for your alignment issue would be to copy the buffer into a local struct.

```
struct x
{
    unsigned long long :0;

    char buffer[512];
};
```

That would give you an aligned buffer to work with.

Comment: This is possible on x86 but it results in a crashing program on platforms that don't support misaligned memory access when the buffer is misaligned. As specified in the question, I'm interested in a portable solution.

Comment: @FUZxxl you can just do the usual "single bytes until aligned" thing then (and then you get a tail too). Annoying, but obviously possible